# Foreach array from push return empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array where the objects are generated from a push that is inside a function, when I try to view the objects directly in the array I am successful, but I am using forEach to add the number of times that an id uses the service, but the result always returns empty.

```
client.onMessage(async message => {

   count_commands.push({id:parseInt(regNumberPhone), age: 1});

});


const count_commands = [],
  hash = Object.create(null),
  result = [];

  count_commands.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.id]) {
        hash[o.id] = { id: o.id, age: 0 };
        result.push(hash[o.id]);
    }
    hash[o.id].age += +o.age;
  });
```

to look de objects in count_commands

```
console.log(count_commands);
Return:
[ { id: 559892099500, age: 1 },
  { id: 559892099500, age: 1 },
  { id: 559892099500, age: 1 } ]
```

but to see the total sum of each id the array returns empty

```
console.log(result);
Return:

    {}
```

I need to return like:

```
[ { id: 559892099500, age: 3 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. i.e. the for loop will return the structure that you require. The problem I am going to guess is that you are registering an event handler that will populate the `count_commands` array only after the `onMessage` event has been received.

If you are trying to iterate the `count_commands` array prior to it being populated you will get back an empty result. I suspect there are other problems also if the `console.log` is returning `{}` instead of `[]`.

You need to modify your code to something similar to as follows

```
const count_commands = [];
const result = [];
const hash = {};

client.onMessage(async message => {
   count_commands.push({id:parseInt(regNumberPhone), age: 1});
   updateResults();
});

function updateResults() {
  count_commands.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.id]) {
        hash[o.id] = { id: o.id, age: 0 };
        result.push(hash[o.id]);
    }
    hash[o.id].age += +o.age;
  });
}
```